# Creating alias for numpy functions

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy

`a=np.square` creates an alias for `pow(x,2)`

Similarly, I want to create an alias for `pow(x,3)` function

```
a = np.power(x2=3)
```

doesn't seem to work

Any workaround?

Answer (score 2):

You are looking for *partial application*, which is not the same thing as an alias. So, the most straightforward way is to define a function:

```
>>> import math
>>> math.pow(3, 2)
9.0
>>> def three_to_the(n): return math.pow(3, n)
...
>>> three_to_the(2)
9.0
>>>
```

There is also a convenience function in `functools` for this:

```
>>> from functools import partial
>>> power_three = partial(math.pow, 3)
>>> power_three(2)
9.0
>>> power_three(3)
27.0
```

Note, `np.square` is **not** an alias for `np.power(x, 2)`, they just act equivalently, but an alias is simply the exact same function (or any object) with a different name.

Comment: Calling `partial` a convenience is an oversimplification, since it can still take whatever arguments the wrapped function can take, whereas `three_to_the` is limited to the single argument used to define it. It's not even a function; it's a class whose instances are callable.

Comment: @chepner Yes, you are correct that `partial` is actually a class that return a callable object, but you can always write a function that gives you the same functionality as partial in that regard, and partial has the major limitation of only being able to handle the *leftmost* positional arguments. So, try implementing `def p(x): return math.power(x, 2)` with partial...